# Do I need to keep the product after a successful chargeback?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, refund, dispute, chargeback

I am in California. I successfully filed a chargeback after a merchant repeatedly failed to send a return label after agreeing to an RMA. I now have my money back, but also a product taking up space in my house.

Can I discard/use/sell the product without worrying that the merchant could come after me later? If not, is there some waiting period after which this would be safe?

Comment: @SRiverNet With due respect, your edit changes the meaning of my question. I don't *want* to keep the product. I want to return it. Failing that, I just don't want it to take up space forever.

Comment: Just send it back on your own then.  If it costs you a few dollars in postage then it may be worth the peace of mind.  Include a letter and keep the postage receipt.  Better yet print out the package tracking history as proof.  I will withdraw my answer, and my apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @SRiverNet That's a good idea. Unfortunately they haven't given me even an address where I could send it. Thanks anyway. :)